# Flutter project compile error after upgrading to 2.0.0

Tags: flutter

I was using Flutter version 1.25 (beta channel) and it worked just fine. After upgrading to version 2.0.0 and switching to stable channel i'm getting this error when i try to run the app either on mobile or web.

```
../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'name' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: name
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      ProgramCompiler._emitSuperTarget (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:5109:41)
#2      ProgramCompiler.visitSuperMethodInvocation (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:5102:24)
#3      SuperMethodInvocation.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:5109:44)
#4      ProgramCompiler._visitExpression (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3623:20)
#5      ProgramCompiler.visitAsExpression (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:5677:18)
#6      AsExpression.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:6062:44)
#7      ProgramCompiler._visitExpression (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3623:20)
#8      ProgramCompiler.visitReturnStatement (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:4152:38)
#9      ReturnStatement.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:7786:43)
#10     ProgramCompiler._visitStatement (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3551:20)
#11     MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:411:31)
#12     ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:340:26)
#13     new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
#14     new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#15     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:28)
#16     ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:211:44)
#17     ProgramCompiler.visitBlock (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3717:62)
#18     Block.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:7048:43)
#19     ProgramCompiler._visitStatement (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3551:20)
#20     ProgramCompiler._emitFunctionScopedBody (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3562:18)
#21     ProgramCompiler._emitSyncFunctionBody.<anonymous closure> (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3355:17)
#22     ProgramCompiler._withLetScope (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:2235:25)
#23     ProgramCompiler._withCurrentFunction (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3389:18)
#24     ProgramCompiler._emitSyncFunctionBody (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3351:17)
#25     ProgramCompiler._emitFunction (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3165:11)
#26     ProgramCompiler._emitMethodDeclaration (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1843:12)
#27     ProgramCompiler._emitClassMethods (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1784:23)
#28     ProgramCompiler._emitClassDeclaration (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:658:21)
#29     ProgramCompiler._emitClass (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:580:21)
#30     List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:403:8)
#31     ProgramCompiler._emitLibrary (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:529:23)
#32     List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:403:8)
#33     ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:394:15)
#34     JavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:144:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#35     FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:632:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#36     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:545:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1105:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
Finished with error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
```

I tried (from Android Studio) `Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean` and `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` but it didn't help.

Comment: Use the `dart fix` to to migrate your Flutter project.

Comment: I ran `dart fix --dry-run` and it said `Nothing to fix!`

Comment: It looks like your `provider` package is several versions out of date. You are on version `3.2.0` when the most recent release  is `5.0.0`. The older package is likely incompatible with the Flutter 2.0.0.

Comment: That worked thank you! Please write it as an answer so that i can set it as the correct answer. Also you can edit your last answer to precise that `dart fix --dry-run` should be executed from the Flutter SDK directory (I first executed it from my project directory)

Comment: You will the latest version of `dart` to  run `dart fix` with the `--dry-run` command: `v2.12`. H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `provider` you're using is on version `3.2.0`. It's likely that this package version is using incompatable methods, objects, etc with Flutter 2.0.0.

The latest version of `provider` is `5.0.0` which supports this new version of Flutter. Try upgrading the package to this version.

Comment: I have the same issue without 'provider' - take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398652/flutter-crash-on-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

#### From the [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix) site.

The `dart fix` command (**added in Dart 2.12**)
finds and fixes two types of issues:

- Analysis issues that have associated automated fixes
  (sometimes called *quick-fixes* or *code actions*)
- Issues that have associated package API migration information

To preview proposed changes, use the `--dry-run` flag:

```
$ dart fix --dry-run
```

To apply the proposed changes, use the `--apply` flag:

```
$ dart fix --apply
```

---

From Flutter 1.X to Flutter 2.X you will see breaking changes. Always review these changes before committing to the upgrade so you understand the changes.