# Flutter CRASH on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Android studio crashes and does not run the project

- after flutter upgrade to 2.0
- flutter doctor has no issues
- dart fix doesn't work, suggested here - [Flutter project compile error after upgrading to 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477979/flutter-project-compile-error-after-upgrading-to-2-0-0)

```
    ===== CRASH =====
    ExceptionCode=-1073741819, ExceptionFlags=0, ExceptionAddress=00007FF62E8D6068
    version=2.13.4 (stable) (Wed Jun 23 13:08:41 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64"
    pid=17144, thread=4592, isolate_group=main(0000024AF5082BB0), isolate=main(0000024AF5087BD0)
    isolate_instructions=24af42c0000, vm_instructions=7ff62e7ffb70
    Stack dump aborted because GetAndValidateThreadStackBounds failed.
    the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

flutter run --verbose :

```
  #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      DefaultResidentCompiler._compile.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/compile.dart:734:13)
           #2      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
           #3      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
           #4      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
           #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:13)
           #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:404:15)
           #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:291:7)
           #8      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:87:11)
           #9      _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:21:11)
           #10     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:251:11)
           #11     _LineSplitterSink.close (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:139:11)
           #12     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:132:24)
           #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
           #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
           #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
           #16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:13)
           #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:404:15)
           #18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:291:7)
           #19     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:87:11)
           #20     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:21:11)
           #21     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:251:11)
           #22     _Utf8ConversionSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:305:20)
           #23     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:81:18)
           #24     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:132:24)
           #25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
           #26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
           #27     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
           #28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:13)
           #29     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:404:15)
           #30     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:291:7)
           #31     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendDone (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:741:19)
           #32     _StreamController._closeUnchecked (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:7)
           #33     _StreamController.close (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:589:5)
           #34     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2167:21)
           #35     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
           #36     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
           #37     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
           #38     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
           #39     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
           #40     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)
           #41     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)
           #42     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)
           #43     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1703:35)
           #44     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1201:18)
           #45     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
           #46     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
           #47     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:120:13)
           #48     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:185:5)
```